# Do not prompt to change password when expired OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, oracle, oledbconnection

```
        string connectionString = String.Format("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;OLEDB.NET=true;User ID={0};password={1};Data Source={2}", username, password, database);
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

        connection.Open();
```

When opening the connection if the oracle password is expired it prompts the user to change the password. I just want it to fail and not prompt them for a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28431/using.htm), you need to add the PwdChgDlg option to your connectionString.

BTW, I searched for "oracle oledb password expire" in my browser.